# React: Couldn't access properties within data after axios loads. Could it have something to do with params?

Tags: json, reactjs, properties, react-router

I'm coding MERN app and I'm almost done with it. However, I am having problems displaying a single customer page with data.

My App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CustomersList from "./components/customers-list";
import customerRewards from './components/customerRewards';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

 
function App() {
 return (
 <Router>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="header">
        <h1>Wow Rewards Program</h1>
      </div>
      <Route path="/" exact component={CustomersList} />
      <Route path='/:id' component={customerRewards} />
    </div>
  </Router>
 );
}
 
export default App;
```

My Customer list Component to list customers in main page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CustomerCard from "./customerCard";

class CustomersList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      customers: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/customers/')
     .then(response => {
       this.setState({ customers: response.data });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
     })
  }
  
  
  render() {
    const customers = this.state.customers;
    console.log("customerList", customers);
    let customersList;

    if(!customers) {
      customersList = "there is no customer record!";
    } else {
      customersList = customers.map((customer, k) =>
        <CustomerCard customer={customer} key={k} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Customers List</h2>
        <div>
          <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Account</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {customersList}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CustomersList;
```

My CustomerCard Component to display each customer

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomerCard = (props) => {
  const  customerCard  = props.customer;

    
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{customerCard.account}</td>
        <td>{customerCard.name}</td>
        <td>
          <Link to={`/${customerCard.account}`}>view</Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  
}

export default CustomerCard;
```

My Customer Rewards Component to list customer details

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class customerRewards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      customerRewards: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // const { accountId } = this.props.match.params;
    console.log("Print id: " + this.props.match.params.id);
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/customers/'+this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(res => {
        // console.log("Print-customerRewards-API-response: " + res.data);
        this.setState({
          customerRewards: res.data
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error from customerRewards");
      })
  };


  render() {

    const customerRewards = this.state.customerRewards;
    console.log("customerID", customerRewards);
    let CustomerItem = <div>
      {customerRewards.purchase_history}
    </div>

    return (
      <div >
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-10 m-auto">
              <br /> <br />
              <Link to="/" className="btn btn-outline-warning float-left">
                  Back
              </Link>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Hello {customerRewards.name}</h1>
              <p className="lead text-center">
                  {customerRewards.account}
              </p>
              <hr /> <br />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            { CustomerItem }
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default customerRewards;
```

this is my .json sample that I uploaded to MongoDB Atlas:

```
[
  {
    "account": "BCE456",
    "name": "JohnDoe",
    "purchase_history": [
      {
      "month": "Month01",
      "transitions": [
        {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      }
    ]
    },
    {
      "month": "Month02",
      "transitions": [
        {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      }
    ]
    }
  ]
  },
  {
    "account": "ABC123",
    "name": "JohnDoe",
    "purchase_history": [
      {
      "month": "Month01",
      "transitions": [
        {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      }
    ]
    },
    {
      "month": "Month02",
      "transitions": [
        {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      },
      {
        "date": "01/01/2010",
        "purchase": 120
      }
    ]
    }
  ]
  }
]
```

I can see that I was able to download the customer details in `console.log("customerID", customerRewards);` However, when I tried to access `{customerRewards.name}`, it won't display the name at all....

[image]

What am I missing? Could it have something to do with the params that I'm trying to link to? I tried to link by `account` instead of `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your piece of state, `customerRewards` is an array when it comes from the API. So even when you declare your initial state with an object `{}`, `customerRewards` is always going to be an array with one element in this case. Could be an issue in your API response - I'm not familiar with MongoDB Atlas or if it creates access patterns for you but you should be able to configure to return a singular object with a unique ID rather than an array of 1 element.

For now you could do:

```
this.setState({
  customerRewards: res.data[0] /** could do res.data.shift() as well */
})
```

I would figure out why you are returning an array if there is only supposed to be one element coming back.

Comment: So something like this? https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

Comment: And beside I set it up in the route in the backend this to call a single customer
`router.route('/:account').get((req, res) => {
  Customer.find({'account': req.params.account})
    .then(customer => res.json(customer))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});`

Comment: Also when I added [0] to this.state.customerRewards[0] and then called something like a name like `this.state.customerRewards[0].name`, it threw an error....

Comment: @KristinaBressler `console.log(customer);` in your backend in the `.then` after your route returns. See if it returns an array or a single object before you return it.

You also may be getting your results from `/customers` instead of `/customers/{id}` if that id isn't coming through right.

Answer (score 0):

just select the element which name you want to get:

```
customerRewards[0].name
```